# Is "and" needed here?

Tags: grammar, coordinating-conjunctions

Could anyone tell me if the following sentence is correct? Do we need an *and* before *funded*?

> The professor undertook the XXXXX research project, aiming at improving the efficiency of the YYYY system, funded by the National Research Agency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence will be misunderstood without ***and***, because then, by [*the proximity rule* (see p. 11)](http://www.writingforresults.net/Acro_3/4_msg/4_grammr/relative.pdf), the reduced relative ***funded by the National Research Agency*** will modify the noun ***system***, not ***project*** as you seem to intend.

Your sentence contains 2 reduced relatives

1. relative clause reduced to present participle:

> *[which is] **aimed***  at improving the efficiency of the YYYY system

2. relative clause reduced to past participle:

> *[which is] **funded*** by the National Research Agency

In order for them to both modify ***project***, you need the coordinating conjunction ***and*** before *funded*. Then there is no ambiguity.

Note that, as indicated in the comments, the idiomatic phrase is

> [*(be) **aimed at*** doing something](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-aimed-at-doing-something)

When you coordinate two reduced relatives by *and*, your sentence will be more successful if you reduce them both to the same kind of participle, (either past or present, mixing them can increase ambiguity and be less elegant).

Comment: Now that you mention it, let's go with aimed at and funded by.

Comment: Was so engrossed in linking the relatives that I missed that...

Comment: Is it to better to keep the comma before "and funded by"?

Comment: Yes, I would keep it, it prepares the reader for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

By switching the word phrases we could arrive at a better reconstruction of the sentence

- The professor undertook the National Research Agency funded XXXXX research project, which aims at improving the efficiency of the YYYY system.